# Как подсчитать количество нод, если нода ссылается сама на себя?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Left;
    public Node Right;
    public object Value;
    public int TotalNodeCount =>
        1 + (Left?.TotalNodeCount ?? 0) + (Right?.TotalNodeCount ?? 0);
}
```

Создаю экземпляр класса:

```
var s = new Node();
s.Left = s;
```

При попытке в дебагере посмотреть, что же получилось - приложение закрывается с невнятной ошибкой (я так полагаю, где-то внутри стэковерфлоу).

Вопрос такой - как правильно сделать и какую статью почитать вот по таким циклическим ссылкам?

Comment: Перед тем как обратиться к `TotalNodeCount` проверить ссылку

Comment: `private int GetCount(Node Node) => Node != null && Node != this ? Node.TotalNodeCount : 0;` Вызвать для Right и Left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Естественно выпадает StackOverflow.

Сам по себе Node не может знать, встречался ли уже этот экземпляр ранее или нет. Поэтому придётся использовать какую-нибудь коллекцию и передавать её дальше, чтобы циклически проверять: был ли этот экземпляр ранее или нет. Для данной задачи достаточно HashSet.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Left;
    public Node Right;
    public object Value;

    public int TotalNodeCount =>
        totalNodeCount(new HashSet<Node>());

    private int totalNodeCount(HashSet<Node> nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.Add(this))
            return 1 + (Left?.totalNodeCount(nodes) ?? 0) + (Right?.totalNodeCount(nodes) ?? 0);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем коллекция? Можно просто проверить ссылается нод на себя или нет...и соответственно делать действие

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а если сделать цепочку в форме кольца? для него достаточно 2 ноды, но `StackOverflow` тут как тут.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц как проверить на то, что ссылается сам на себя?

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу править код класса. Но идея с хэшсетом хорошая, схоронил. Вообще, проблема стэковерфлоу в таком простом примере меня удивила, мне казалось, что компилятор мог бы ее и обнаружить.

Comment: @DmitryMalikov путем сравнения [попробуйте тут](https://rextester.com/NUJZ5236)

Comment: @DmitryMalikov ну, компилятор - это не анализатор кода, всё-таки. Он его только собирает из того, что вы ему написали. А для анализа есть специальные статические анализаторы. Правда, я не знаю, справятся ли они с таким случаем - не пользовался никогда.

Comment: @DmitryMalikov да и тут случай неочевидный, так как ошибка не гарантированно будет. И что вообще говорить, если VS не предупредит даже в таком случае: `class Node { Node first = new Node(); }`